# jQuery: second detach ignored automatically?

Tags: jquery, detach

Should i make such check, before detaching?

```
if(for_detach.parent().length) {for_detach.detach();}
```

or jquery automatically do it?

Thanks ;)

**Update**

Same with `wr.find('iframe:hidden').show();` and different others situations.

Comment: Run `detach()` twice and see whether you get an error.

Comment: I won't get an error. But probably more unwanted actions inside framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src).

In case of [`detach`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L272):

```
detach: function( selector ) {
    return this.remove( selector, true );
},

// keepData is for internal use only--do not document
remove: function( selector, keepData ) {
    for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( !selector || jQuery.filter( selector, [ elem ] ).length ) {
            if ( !keepData && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                jQuery.cleanData( elem.getElementsByTagName("*") );
                jQuery.cleanData( [ elem ] );
            }

            if ( elem.parentNode ) {
                elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
            }
        }
    }

    return this;
},
```

So yes, jQuery will make sure that there is a parent before it detaches from it, but it does not *ignore* the call.

It depends on the function whether calling it twice has any effect.

Of course if you call `show` twice then the second call will not have any (visible) effect. But that does not mean that jQuery is not doing anything in the back. Have a look at the [`show` implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L22).

Comment: Thanks mate. It seems it's time for me to dig sources. :)